# Convert C# datetime to php mysql

Tags: php

I have to save `DateTime` which is coming from .Net Application in a MySql database with PHP, but I am not able to do so.

I have tried this for example, but it's not working:

```
    $date = "7/24/2013 11:40:53 AM";
    $datetime = new DateTime ($date);
    print $datetime->date;
```

What is happening is: The code is working fine when I am debugging this code line by line, means it is printing `2013-07-24 11:40:53`, but without debugging it is not printing, I am not able to understand why is this happening; I am stuck.

Comment: What has C# to do here? Anyway, you're looking for [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: What do you mean by "debugging the code line by line" ? Can you show us exactly what you are doing ?

Comment: @ Leri C# Datetime is coming in a sync service which i have coded in php.

Comment: @Loonie I am executing code with the help of debug option in the software, codelobster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method of DateTime object.

```
$date = "7/24/2013 11:40:53 AM";
$datetime = new DateTime ($date);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function.

```
echo strtotime($datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the **[FORMAT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)**

```
<?php
$date1 = "7/24/2013 11:40:53 AM";

$datetime = new DateTime ($date1);
print $datetime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

**OUTPUT**

> 2013/07/24 11:40:53